# Count(*) for View returning different results on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am working on an ETL optimization problem and that requires creating a temp table that could be merged with the final table. Currently I have a couple Views that are used to load the final table and that is taking a lot of time. I tried to take the SQL logic from the view and created a temp table and noticed that the values in the temp table do not match the values in the final table. To look deeper I was running `count(*)` on the view couple of times and noticed that the result for total row count is different for every run by about 10/15 rows give or take. The view has 16 columns from 9 tables which load only once a day. So the time when I run the `count(*)` the underlying data does not change but the result of the count from the view does change.

This is on a SQL Server 2016 server. I have tried looking into the View logic and nothing stands out as odd. I have tried doing a `count(*)` on the tables that loads this view and the counts for the tables do not change. I have also tried to create 2 column table from the view logic to simplify the problem and tried an `EXCEPT` command and that still yields about 20 rows of inconsistent values between the 2 column table created from the same exact view logic.

Here is a reproduction of the VIEW definition that has the row count inconsistency

```
USE [PROD]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW Base_View 
AS

select 
concat(x,   y,  z)feild1
,*
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a,b ORDER BY some_Date) AS rec_num
,count(a) OVER(PARTITION BY a) AS rec_total
from (
    SELECT 
    case when RESULT='stored value' and e.code is not null then 'x' else '' end x
    ,case when RESULT='stored value 2' and r.l_id is not null then 'y' else '' end y
    ,case when RESULT in ('stored value 3','stored value 4') and t.amount is not null then 'z' else '' end z
    ,case when 
        CASE WHEN 
            (m.status = 'stored value 4' OR m.status = 'stored value 5') 
            AND m.bal < 0 
            THEN 
                CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,m.due,m.SNAP_DATE) < 0 
                    THEN 0 
                    ELSE DATEDIFF(day,m.due,m.SNAP_DATE)
                END 
            ELSE 0 
        END=0 AND w.W_ID is null AND m.status<>'stored value 5'
    then case 
        when RESULT in ('stored value 5','stored value 4')  
            then case when isnull(AMOUNT,0)<>0
                        then 'abc' 
                        else 'def' end
            else 'abc' end
    else 'def' 
    end imp_feild
    ,result
    ,es.emp_id
    ,concat(es.fname,' ',es.lname)task_emp
    ,concat(e.fname,' ',e.lname)ext_emp
    ,case when RESULT ='stored value' then t.P_STATUS else null end p_status
    ,t.CREATE_DATE
    ,t.l_key
    ,t.l_id
    ,m.status
    ,cast(w.wodate as date)wo_date
    ,rm.balance refi_balance,rnl.LOAN_key refi_loan,r.effective refi_effective
    ,case trancode when 'ext' then m.payment else null end ext_amount,e.entered ext_entered,e.effective ext_effective
      FROM 
       (
       select t0.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t0.some_KEY,cast(t0.CREATE_DATE as date),t0.output 
                                     ORDER BY t0.some_KEY,cast(t0.CREATE_DATE as date),t0.output ) AS SEQ_NUM
            from base_table_1 t0
            left join base_table_2 e0 
            on t0.c_e_key=e0.e_key
            where t0.active_rec_ind='Y' 
            and t0.output in (d,e,f,g) 
            and (t0.output2 in (j,k)
                or ISNULL(e0.some_KEY,'h') in ('u','w'))
            ) t
      join 
      base_table_3 l
      on t.loan_sf_id=l.loan_sf_id
      and t.active_rec_ind='Y'
      join base_table_4 m
      on 
      t.SOME_DATE=m.SNAP_DATE
      and   t.L_ID=m.L_ID
      left 
      join base_table_5 es
      on t.c_emp_key=es.emp_key
      left 
      join base_table_6 r
      on l.l_id=r.l_old_id
      and r.entered between dateadd(day,0,cast(t.CREATE_DATE as date)) and dateadd(day,0,t.SOME_DATE)
      left 
      join base_table_7 w
      on l.l_id=w.l_id
      and w.wodate between cast(t.CREATE_DATE_ETZ as date) and dateadd(day,0,t.SOME_DATE)
      left
      join base_table_8 wl
      on w.l_id=wl.l_id
      left
      join base_table_8 rnl
      on r.l_new_id=rnl.l_id
      left
      join base_table_8 rol
      on r.l_old_id=rol.l_id
      left 
      join base_table_4 rm
      on 
      dateadd(day,-1,r.effective)=rm.SNAP_DATE
      and   rol.L_ID=rm.L_ID  
      left 
      join 
       (select e0.*,ew.value_1,ew.new_key,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e0.L_ID,e0.ENT ORDER BY e0.L_ID,e0.ENT) AS SEQ_NUM
            from base_table_9 e0
              join base_table_5 ew 
              on e0.EMP_ID=ew.EMP_ID
            where e0.code='a'
            ) e
      on l.sid=e.sid
      and e.code='a' and RESULT='stored value 5'
      and e.entered between cast(t.CREATE_DATE as date) and dateadd(day,0,t.HOLD_DATE)
      AND e.SEQ_NUM=t.SEQ_NUM
      and ((isnumeric(e.roll_key)=1 and isnumeric(es.roll_key)=1  and e.roll_key=es.roll_key)
      or  ((isnumeric(e.roll_key)=0  or isnumeric(es.roll_key)=0) and e.FNAME+e.LNAME=es.FNAME+es.LNAME))
      where t.RESULT in ('abc','def')
      and cast(t.CREATE_DATE as date) between cast(dateadd(month,-12,getdate()) as date) and cast(getdate() as date)
      and (AGENT in ('lmn', 'pqr')
        or ISNULL(es.VKEY,'stored value 8') in ('xx','yy','zz'))
)x
where imp_feild='abc'
and concat(x,   y,  z)<>''
or imp_feild='def'

GO
```

Expected result is that it should return a consistent number for the row count and that hopefully should solve the inconsistent values problem on the temp table.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This query is so obfuscated you can't even tell what is going on. The formatting doesn't help either. Are you saying you run the view and you get one count, then immediately run it again and get a different count? And during that time the base tables have not changed?

Comment: Yes, underlying data does not change, that is the problem I am dealing with, base tables load by 12 pm and I run the view at 3 pm and it takes 20 mins to get the count of rows to be equal to 55,010 And I run the view at 3:21 pm and this time I get 55,025 rows

Comment: Well you have logic in your queries that use the current system time as part of the rows it returns. So it would only make sense that the row count would change if there are any rows that would no longer be valid or rows that become valid during the two distinct time windows. And I full agree with the answer below. Select * in a view is a terrible idea. It not only does not refresh but if you add a new column and then drop a previous column the data moves.

Answer (score 1):

Your query has `between cast(dateadd(month,-12,getdate()) as date) and cast(getdate() as date)` near the bottom.  Of course the result of getdate() will be different with each execution and each call to getdate().  That will affect the result.

BTW, having * in your SELECT list is not a good idea. You should only return the columns needed.  It makes the view results vulnerable to changes in the underlying tables.

There are a few other things that wouldn't pass code review where I work but that's kinda OT, I think.

Comment: I am running the View counts on the same day and the getdate() is cast as date which is returning the same date. I am not comparing count from different dates.

Comment: In that case, I would say that of the 9-10 tables being joined, at least one of them is changing between queries to the view, even though you don't think it is.  First thing I'd do is get rid of the * in the select list and replace it with the columns needed, clean it up with two-part names everywhere and proper formatting.  Then I'd be able to see better what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment. Using * in a view is a very bad idea. Not only does the view NOT update (unless you execute sp_refreshview) when you change the base table you can actually get some very interesting things happening.

Check this out as an example of just how bad this can be.

```
create table ViewExample (Col1 int, Col2 int)
go

create view ViewExampleView as select * from ViewExample

go

insert ViewExample select 1, 2

go

select * from ViewExampleView --obviously we get just a single column

alter table ViewExample add Col3 int --add a new column to the table, surely the view will pick this up?

go

insert ViewExample select 3, 4, 5 --insert a new row with data in all three columns

go

select * from ViewExampleView --what??? The view says select * but we only get Col1 and Col2?

alter table ViewExample drop column Col2 --Oops we decide to drop this column because we don't need it anymore

select * from ViewExampleView --What in the world? Col2 doesn't exist in the table, why is it in the view? And what the heck is going on here. The data from Col3 is now moved to Col2

drop view ViewExampleView
drop table ViewExample
```

Notice how in the last select from the view that the data from Col3 is being displayed in Col2. If this doesn't convince you to stop using * in views (and pretty much everywhere) I don't know what will.

Comment: Makes my wonder why using CREATE or ALTER VIEW with a SELECT * in it does not just throw an error. I can't think of a reason why it should ever be allowed, or even preferable.

Comment: @jrdevdba SQL Server is pretty consistent in that it will let you do stupid things, like using select * in a view. I think it would be tricky to have the parser figure that out because you could have an exists subquery where using select * is perfectly fine. It would be nice if it would toss up a warning though.